# making a varchar column to be a PRIMARY KEY

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, primary-key, alter

I had made a table :

```
id int,
name varchar(50),
addr varchar(50),
location varchar(20)
```

Now i want to make `addr` column to be `PRIMARY KEY COLUMN`. I tried a script:

```
alter table aaa
add constraint pk_addr primary key(addr)
```

But it shows an error and the data in that column is also `NOT NULL` and `UNIQUE`.My question is that can we make a `varchar` column to be `primary key`,If yes then the above `alter` column script is correct or not.

Comment: Maybe you're trying to alter a column that has a value with `null` or some values are the same, and we know that primary key must be unique..

Comment: When you have those problems, try making the changes through the SQL Management Studio and, instead of doing Save, do Generate Script and look at the generated script.

Comment: @BkSantiago i have mentioned that the value in the column is NOT NULL and is UNIQUE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to specify that column `aaa` is not nullable:

```
create table aaa (id int, name varchar(50), addr varchar(50), location varchar(20));

alter table aaa alter column addr varchar(50) not null;
alter table aaa add constraint pk_addr primary key(addr);
```